80s/90s TV show or Movie where antagonist molests/rapes female but protagonist get vengence and stuffs antagonist gold watch in his mouth
I know title/plot sounds very generic and cliche. But I happened to watch this film unsupervised as a child and it has affected my views on women and my sexuality. I'm trying to find the title/name so I can rewatch/process it as the adult I am now. 
These are the only details I can remember about the program
Woman gets raped/molested on what might be a bus or subway. It might be New York.
Woman may have black/burnette hair
Man who rapes the woman may have had a gold watch (camera presents it as a plot device)
Man who gets revenge for the woman who gets raped puts gold watch into the rapist mouth and makes him eat it or chew it.
That's all the details I can remember. I hope someone out there on the internet can identify this tv show/movie.

Kudos for seeking out this movie to process it as an adult. That's a great way to grow personally. :)

Sounds like Kinjite: Forbidden Subjects from 1989 with Charles Bronson. From IMDb:

A Tokyo businessman (Hiroshi Hada), transferred to L.A, molests a teenage girl on a train. It turns out that the girl is the daughter of a vice cop [Bronson]. But in one of those plot twists that can only occur in the movies, the cop is assigned to find the businessman's own daughter who has been kidnapped and forced into a teen prostitution ring.

You can see the scene where Bronson forces a villain to swallow a gold watch here:




This is the movie....
Thank you so much. I hope this gives me the understanding I'm looking for.
